# Estimating Ingredients for 1kg Dough with Specific Nutritional Facts and Olive Oil Percentage

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate an estimate of the ingredients required to make 1kg of dough. The ingredients include wheat flour, sugar, extra virgin olive oil (24%) and almonds. I have the nutritional facts for each 100g of the dough and the percentage of extra virgin olive oil.

Here are the nutritional facts per 100g:

| Nutrient | Oil Cakes | Flour | Extra Virgin Olive Oil | Sugar | Almonds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Calories | 433 kcal | 350 kcal | 120 kcal per tbsp (14g) | 387 kcal | 579 kcal |
| Protein | 4.8g | 10g | 0g | 0g | 21.15g |
| Carbohydrates | 57.1g | 73g | 0g | 99.98g | 21.55g |
| Sugar | 24.1g | 0.6g | 0g | 99.98g | 4.35g |
| Fat | 22.6g | 3g | 14g per tbsp (14g) | 0g | 49.93g |
| Fiber |  | 2.7g | 0g | 0g | 12.5g |
| Salt | 0.65g | 0.02g | 0g | 0g | 0g |

The amount of the ingredients should be:

- Flour > Sugar > Olive Oil > Almonds
- None of the amounts can be lower than 0

How can I estimate the amount of each ingredient required to make 1kg of dough based on that information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here is how I would approach estimating the ingredients to make 1kg of dough based on the nutritional information provided:

Let's start with the known amount - 240g of olive oil for 24% of 1kg dough.

Then we can set up equations based on the nutritional facts:

1. Total calories per 100g dough = 433
   350*(f/100) + 387*(s/100) + 120*(24/14) + 579*(a/100) = 433
2. Total protein per 100g dough = 4.8
   10*(f/100) + 21.15*(a/100) = 4.8
3. Total carbohydrates per 100g dough = 57.1
   73*(f/100) + 99.98*(s/100) + 21.55*(a/100) = 57.1
4. Total sugar per 100g dough = 24.1
   0.6*(f/100) + 99.98*(s/100) + 4.35*(a/100) = 24.1
5. Total fat per 100g dough = 22.6
   3*(f/100) + 14*(24/14) + 49.93*(a/100) = 22.6

Where:
f = grams of flour per 100g dough
s = grams of sugar per 100g dough
a = grams of almonds per 100g dough
o = grams of olive oil per 100g dough = 24g

I have less unknowns than equations, and I've thought that by choosing to solve with less equations I will loose information and make the estimate less precise than it could be.